# Tracking a device's IP Changes inside Network

Tags: c#, ip, intranet

We are pulling data out of the machines in a machine shop. There is a software adapter on the machine that is pumping out the data to a specific port. There is then a network "agent" that takes that data and puts it in a readable format.

**Here's the issue**: The agent finds the data by having the IP address of the device. But when the device gets assigned a new IP address periodically, the agent loses connection to the machine until it is manually fixed. I would like to have a way of searching the list of network devices for the machine when the IP changes to then give the agent the correct IP.

I program mainly in c# and have scoured the internet for something like this and have had no luck. Basically I need to A. Detect IP change of specific device. B. get New IP. and C. Update Agent to correct IP.

NOTE: I have been told we are not allowed to set the machine to a static IP for some reason. I know this would be the ideal and quickest fix, but I have been told it is off the table of options.

Expected results would be an input such as Device Name, or other particular static/constant variable tied to the machine and have it output the current IP on the network.

input: "I200ST" (Device Name, which is unique on the network)
output: 192.168.1.XXX

Comment: So DHCP is running?  If whatever is serving DHCP addresses can also perform DNS updates then you can just maintain a list of self updating host names

Comment: Thanks! i believe I am on the right track now. I found out how to do a scan of a subnet an retrieve the Hostname and IP. Currently implementing it into a service that will monitor for changes, and then edit the xml file with the correct IP when it finds the inconsistency.